# I want to save different datasets in different folders depending on which list they belong to

Tags: r, list, dataset

I have different lists of datasets

```
LIST 1
mydata1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1:4), year=rep("2010",5),Weight=c(50,50:53),Height=c(175,175:178))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=6:10, year=rep("2011",5),Weight=c(52:56),Height=c(180:184))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=11:15, year=rep("2012",5),Weight=c(61:65),Height=c(178:182))

mydatalist<-list(mydata1=mydata1,
     mydata2=mydata2,
     mydata3=mydata3)
```

and

```
LIST 2

mydata1<-data.frame(ID=c(11,11:14), year=rep("2010",5),Weight=c(60,60,51:53),Height=c(185,185,175:177))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=16:20, year=rep("2011",5),Weight=c(62:66),Height=c(170:174))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=21:25, year=rep("2012",5),Weight=c(63:67),Height=c(168:172))

mydatalist2<-list(mydata1=mydata1,
                 mydata2=mydata2,
                 mydata3=mydata3)
```

I created a function to manage the data on each of the datasets and save the clean datasets in different folders. I have included the save function in my function. I know that it is possible to perform the saving task outside of the `my_function`. But I want to automate my data management as much as possible.

So the outputs of `mydatalist1` should be stored in `path 1` and the outputs of `mydatalist2` in `path 2`.

```
my_function<-function(data){
  library(tidyverse)
  data$duplicated<-duplicated(data)
  sum_duplicated<-sum(data$duplicated)
  data<-data%>%filter(duplicated==F)
  number_row<-dim(data)[1]
  data$BMI<-round(data$Weight/((data$Height/100)^2),2)
  return(list(data=data,number_row=number_row,sum_duplicated=sum_duplicated,
              save(data,file=paste0("C:/Users/MY_NAME/Dropbox/PC (2)/Desktop/OUTPUT1/",
                                    "data_",as.character(unique(data$year)),".RData"))))}






myls<-list()
myls2<-list()

#FOR LIST 1
for(i in 1:length(mydatalist)){
 myls[[i]]<- my_function(mydatalist[[i]])
 }

# FOR LIST 2
for(i in 1:length(mydatalist2)){
  myls2[[i]]<- my_function(mydatalist2[[i]])
  }
```

I would like to put in my function some codes that allow to save the output in `path:paste0("C:/Users/MY_NAME/Dropbox/PC (2)/Desktop/OUTPUT1/","data_",as.character(unique(data$year)),".RData")` if the list is `mydatalist1` and in `path:paste0("C:/Users/MY_NAME/Dropbox/PC (2)/Desktop/OUTPUT1/",           "data_",as.character(unique(data$year)),".RData")` otherwise (that is, the list is `mydatalist2`) .
I think it's a bit complicated with the way I created my function, since it's `data` the argument in the function.
I don't know if it's possible to access the two lists to save their elements in the corresponding folders

I just want to change this part of the code in the function in order to save elements of `mydatalist1` in folder `OUTPUT1` and elements of `mydatalist2` in `OUTPUT2`

```
return(list(data=data,number_row=number_row,sum_duplicated=sum_duplicated,
                  save(data,file=paste0("C:/Users/MY_NAME/Dropbox/PC (2)/Desktop/OUTPUT../",
                                        "data_",as.character(unique(data$year)),".RData"))))
```

Comment: You could add a argument that defines which path to use in `function (data, path = "myls")` and define something like `if (path == "myls") path <- paste0("C:/User...`

Comment: Yes, a good idea. I hadn't thought of this,
I have to specify in the function which list it is and not the function to determine it Thank you

Comment: Using the object name to define the function's behavior is possible but definitely not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're correct that since the `data` argument takes a dataframe rather than a list, it doesn't know or care which list the dataframe came from.

I think the best solution is to add an identifier field to each dataframe.

After you assign dataframes to each list, you can do that with a for loop:

```
mydata1<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1:4), year=rep("2010",5),Weight=c(50,50:53),Height=c(175,175:178))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=6:10, year=rep("2011",5),Weight=c(52:56),Height=c(180:184))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=11:15, year=rep("2012",5),Weight=c(61:65),Height=c(178:182))

mydatalist<-list(mydata1=mydata1,
                 mydata2=mydata2,
                 mydata3=mydata3)

for (i in 1:length(mydatalist)) {
  mydatalist[[i]]$list <- 1
}
```

Then, your return statement will look like this:

```
return(
    list(data = data, 
         number_row = number_row, 
         sum_duplicated = sum_duplicated,
         save(data, 
              file = paste0('OUTPUT', 
                             data$list[1], ## THIS IS WHERE IT ASSIGNS THE OUTPUT FOLDER
                             '/', 'data_', as.character(unique(data$year)), 
                             '.RData'))
        )
      )
```

ALTERNATIVELY, you can change it so the argument is the list, and then assign it to different folders based on the name of the list. Instead of using the for loop to call the function on each item of the list, you would have a for loop inside the function that iterates through the list.

One more note: if you move the `library(tidyverse)` command outside of the function, it won't have to run it every time you call the function.

Comment: Thank you @tamarack, but should I add an additionnal argument to my function or add an ifstatement ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do either; the additional argument is unnecessary because the field is part of the data frame that you read in and the if statement is unnecessary because the $list field is incorporated into the paste0() statement in the file name. I.E. if the value of the list field is 1, then the paste0() returns "OUTPUT1/data_" etc